# Hyperplane intersects submanifold transversally

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ an n-dimensional submanifold. Show that there is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^p$ that intersects $M$ transversally.

My ideas:

I shall use the theorem of Sard but I don't really know how to apply it. I can write the hyperplane as $H^{p-1}=f^{-1}(c)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R},\, f(x_1,...,x_p)=x_k$ with $k\in\{1,...,p\}$. Also what I have to show is that $T_xM\oplus T_xH^{p-1}=\mathbb{R}^{p}$ for all $x\in M\cap H^{p-1}$. I know that $T_x H^{p-1}=H^{p-1}$ and therefore I must "only" find $H^{p-1}$ such that it intersects $M$ at a point or points where $T_x M$ spans at least the "missing dimension" from $H^{p-1}$. The theorem of Sard tells me that the critical points of every differentiable map between two differentiable manifolds have measure zero. I don't know which map I have to use. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You seem to consider only the coordinate hyperplanes but not the oblique ones.

Comment: @Berci oh, you are right. However, I don't see how that helps me either.

Comment: Do you know the Transversality Theorem, as opposed to just Sard?

Comment: @TedShifrin I know this theorem but I don't see how to use it. Could you give me another hint?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: Consider the map $F\colon M\times S^{p-1} \to\Bbb R$ given by
$F(x,v) = x\cdot v$. This is a submersion. Therefore, for almost all $v\in S^{p-1}$, $0$ is a regular value of $F_v\colon M\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't know how that helps me. From this I could conclude that $F_v^{-1}(\{0\})=v^{\perp}$ is a submanifold of $M$. The transversality theorem tells me if I have $f:M\to N$ differentiable and $Z\subset N$ a submanifold with $f\pitchfork N$ that $f^{-1}(Z)$ is a submanifold of $M$.

Comment: Look at The Transversality Theorem, p. 68 of Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: I guess Wikipedia refers to this as the Parametric Transversality Theorem ...

Comment: I'm sorry, if I insulted you by deleting this question. I appreciate your efforts very much. However your approach was not the right one for me. The book you mentioned has a different transversality theorem than the one I have learned. Meanwhile I found another solution. Tell me if you are curious to see it.